# pass multiple data into delete button in ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I need to pass 2 variables in the delete button but I don't know why it was only passing one variable.

Below is my DELETE icon.

```
<a class="delete_employee" data-emp-id="<?php echo $row_dg["emp_id"]; ?>" data-usr-id="<?php echo $sessID; ?>" href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        </a>
```

Now is the AJAX request

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('.delete_employee').click(function(e){   
   e.preventDefault();   
   var empid = $(this).attr('data-emp-id');
   var usrid = $(this).attr('data-usr-id');
   var parent = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr");
   bootbox.dialog({
        message: "Are you sure you want to Delete ?",
        title: "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Delete !",
        buttons: {
            success: {
                  label: "No",
                  className: "btn-success",
                  callback: function() {
                  $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
              }
            },
            danger: {
              label: "Delete!",
              className: "btn-danger",
              callback: function() {       
               $.ajax({        
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'deleteRecords1.php',
                    data: 'usrid='+usrid+'&empid='+empid

               })
               .done(function(response){        
                    bootbox.alert(response);
                    parent.fadeOut('slow');        
               })
               .fail(function(){        
                    bootbox.alert('Error....');               
               })              
              }
            }
        }
   });   
});  
 });
```

and below my PHP file to update the record.

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['empid'] && $_REQUEST['usrid']) {
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_dies SET is_deleted='1', deleted_id='".$_REQUEST['usrid']."'  WHERE emp_id='".$_REQUEST['empid']."'";
$resultset = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($db));
if($resultset) {
    echo "Record Deleted!";
}
}?>
```

So, as I have said, it is passing only 1 variable which is the empid and usrid is missing.

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, does the AJAX request contain the value at all?  What is the exact data on that request?  If it's not there, when you debug the JavaScript, is that variable being set at all?  Side note: Your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.

Comment: Yes, this can be debugged with your browser's debugging tools. First check that the delete button actually does have a value for usrid. If it does then use the javascript debugger to see what happens in the ajax call. Talking about your ajax call, where is it? Ah, I see it. Yes, see the answer on how to provide the data.

Answer (score -1):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```

Notice how "data:" is handled here. So your code would be

```
$.ajax({        
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'deleteRecords1.php',
  data: { usrid: usrid, empid: empid }
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think the way he's sending data is incorrect. He has probably the issue of not getting the data into the variables.